# Creating a conditional variable whose value=dataframe colnames

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have  a dataset(`df`),

```
ID   A   B   C   D   E   F 
1    0   0   1   1   1   1 
2    0   0   0   0   0   0 
3    0   1   0   0   0   0
```

I am trying to write a function that would give me the names of all columns that have the value 1 making my dataset look like this and I have no idea where to start.

```
ID     A    B    C    D   E   F  NewCol 
1      0    0    1    1   1   1   C,D,E,F
2      0    0    0    0   0   0   NA
3      0    1    0    0   0   0   B
```

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach

```
Newdf <- transform(df, 
          NewCol=sapply(apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) 
            colnames(df[,-1])[x==1]), 
                        paste0, collapse=","))

levels(Newdf$NewCol)[levels(Newdf$NewCol)==""] <- "NA"
Newdf
# ID A B C D E F  NewCol
# 1  1 0 0 1 1 1 1 C,D,E,F
# 2  2 0 0 0 0 0 0      NA
# 3  3 0 1 0 0 0 0       B
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` to do row-wise operations. `as.logical` converts 0 to `FALSE` and 1 to `TRUE`. Then use logical indexing on the column names.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[as.logical(x)], collapse=", "))
```

`paste` is used to gather all column names into one character object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, using "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)

## `melt` your data
dfL <- melt(df, id.vars="ID")

## Use `dcast` to paste the "variable" values together
temp <- dcast(dfL, ID ~ value, value.var="variable", 
              fun.aggregate=paste, collapse = ",", 
              fill = NA_character_)
```

The output at this point looks like:

```
temp
#   ID           0       1
# 1  1         A,B C,D,E,F
# 2  2 A,B,C,D,E,F    <NA>
# 3  3   A,C,D,E,F       B
```

This can be `merge`d with the original dataset:

```
merge(df, temp)
merge(df, temp[c("ID", "TRUE")])
```